# How can I get the hosting url instead of functions url in firebase functions for https

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have dynamically generated urls that I need to create for staging and production environments. I am doing a mix of Firebase hosting and functions.  I am also using Firebase config to route urls to my Firebase functions "app". When I try to get the hosting url when I visit my site with req.get('host') inside a Firebase function I get the functions url. How can I get the Hosting url? - the url that triggered the firebase function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you examine the contents of `req.headers`, you'll find some attributes of interest:

- `host`: The host of Cloud Functions, e.g. "us-central1-YOUR-PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net:
- `x-forwarded-host`: Your Firebase Hosting host, e.g. "YOUR-PROJECT.firebaseapp.com"
- `x-forwarded-proto`: The protocol of the original request, e.g. "https"
- `x-original-url`: The URL path of the original request, e.g. "/test"

Between three of those (the ones that start with "x-"), you could concatenate them together to get the original URL.

I don't know if these headers are fully documented and supported.

Comment: `x-forwarded-host` FTW!!!! I have a custom domain (as opposed to the firebaseapp.com address), and was getting `myproject.cloudfunctions.net` out of `req.hostname`. However, `req.headers['x-forwarded-host']` gives me  `myproject.mydomain.mytld`. Thanks Doug!

Comment: The following code is what is use to get the original URL a user would add in the bowser or via a fetch request. 


`const url = \`${req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"]}://${req.headers["x-forwarded-host"]}${req.headers["x-forwarded-url"]}\`;`

Comment: Note that while this will work, if a malicious user calls the function directly, they will just be able to set their own `x-forwarded-host`/etc headers on the request, which depending on how your app uses them, might cause a security issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using functions callable, you can find the information from

`context.rawRequest.headers.origin`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the original URL that the user typed is not available in the request that you get in Cloud Functions. The rewrite happens on a different server, and no information is passed along.

Comment: You can cobble it together using some custom headers in the Express request object, but I don't know if these are fully supported.

Comment: Good to know ... However I think it's an important but missing feature.

Comment: You often need to supply a redirect URL or check a webhook signature that needs the full URL.  Can't do that without hard wiring the original URL into the code. Yuk!