# How to retrieve original host header on functions.https.Request?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a firebase cloud function that checks whether a user is signed in or not before allowing access to the requested page. If the Authentication header is not present in the HTTP request, then the user is redirected to the login page. Here is the code implemented:

```
exports.dashboard = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if ((!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    res.redirect(req.headers.host + "/login.html")
  }
  else {
    //check for Firebase ID Token and return the requested page 
  }
});
```

The problem with this code is that ***req.headers.host*** does not return the original HTTP Request host header value, instead it comes back with the cloud function server address in which the function is running.

I also implemented URL rewriting, so this cloud function is actually triggered by an HTTPS Request as follows:

```
"hosting": {
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/dashboard.html",
    "function": "dashboard"
  } ]
}
```

**EDIT**
The fact that I chose to rewrite an HTTPS Request to a Cloud Function HTTPS Request could cause this issue? Not sure how Firebase Hosting handles URL rewriting internally, but it seems like a new request is triggered from cloud server so the original HTTPS Request from the browser is lost (at least the host header shows that). Using Firebase Emulator, the HTTPS Request is posted from localhost:5000, but when writing req.headers.host to the console (from onRequest(req,res) function) it outputs localhost:5001, which is Functions server emulator.

Comment: An HTTPS Cloud Function handler has the same signature as an Express app: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

Comment: The fact that chose to rewrite an HTTPS Request to a Cloud Function HTTPS Request could cause this issue? Not sure how Hosting handles URL rewriting internally, but it seems like a new request is triggered from cloud server so the original HTTPS Request from the browser is lost (at least the host header shows that). Using firebase emulator, the request is posted from localhost:5000 but when writing req.headers.host to the console inside the onRequest(req,res) function, it outputs localhost:5001, which is Functions server emulator.

Comment: I also updated my question to reflect this observation above

Comment: Did you try on a deployed Cloud Function?

Comment: Yes - same behavior. It printed the Cloud Function prod URL instead of the Hosting URL (original caller)

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish here is a basic login feature using Firebase Auth and cloud functions , however, as I am learning more about Firebase, it seems to me it works better with SPA frontend instead of classic HTML+ JS pages - specially because Firebase hosting handles static content only, so the authentication/authorization should be deferred to cloud function. I should not be facing this type of issue to build such basic an popular feature, which makes me believe I have not designed the right solution to my use case and I may be trying to reinvent the wheel as lack of knowledge

Comment: Yes, it is clear that it will be easier to have an SPA which uses the JS SDKs (Firestore, Cloud Storage, etc) than to use Cloud Functions and hosting to expose some "home-made" REST APIs. The JS SDKs are exactly done for that: they are actually build on top of the Firebase REST APIs and aim at simplifying the interaction between the FE and BE.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195552/how-can-i-get-the-hosting-url-instead-of-functions-url-in-firebase-functions-for):

```
req.headers['x-forwarded-host']
```

Comment: Amazing, Pete! Thanks for sharing this info. I will give it a try to double check it fits my needs.